# Add CSS class on selecting radio button when getting row data table

Tags: jquery, css, radio-button

My code is here to fetch a row. Now I want to add a CSS class in this snippet when selecting radio button.

jQuery Snippet

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("input: radio").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
           var empid = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").text();
           $("#getreco").val(empid);

            var empname = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").text();
            $("#getreco1").val(empname);

            var empdes = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").text();
            $("#getreco2").val(empdes);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: **1.** you can add class use `$(this).addClass("special")` then add css in your stylesheet to class **2.** you ca use `$(this).css("property","value")` directly

Comment: I have done this, but no response is getting

Comment: you should look at F12 and see if you have any error or if the css apply to DOM

Comment: Ok great let me try to do this

Comment: BTW the comment above is to add class to the radiobutton not to dr/td

Comment: when I select the radio button, tr tag access CSS class, but nothing done.                
                    like this                                                                                                                 <tr class=".highlight">
                         <td>2</td>
                         <td>Irfana Saleem</td>
                         <td>Reports Auditor</td>
                         <td><input type="radio" class=".rad" name="radi"></td>

                       </tr>

Comment: remove `.` from `class` (`class="highlight`  NOT `class=".highlight"`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to add class to the radio button and css according to added class

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).addClass("rd");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.rd {
  margin: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="radio" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```